# Grails Spock Testing service call with direct SQL query cannot find discriminator column (Hibernate Mixin)

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, h2, spock

I have a Spock test that fails because a query cannot find the 'class' column related to the discriminator in GORM.

I suspect my issue is with how I am using (or misusing) Spock, but I can't find an example of a test similar to my own (simplified code).

I have an entity which has a discriminator

```
class OrderEnt extends DataObjectEnt {

Boolean orderable
Date date
String name
String termUID
String comment

static mapping = {
    table 'elp_order'
    discriminator value:"ORDER"
    id generator:'uuid', length:39
}
}
```

And I have a service method which only does a direct SQL query to the db and returns the result (simplified query)

```
def getListSystemOrders(){

    def sql = Sql.newInstance(dataSource)
    String select = "SELECT os.id, os.name, os.speciality_id, os.location_id, os.status_id, os.date, os.comment, osh.id orderHeaders\n" +
            "   from elp_order os\n" +
            "     LEFT JOIN elp_order_head osh\n" +
            "       ON os.id = osh.order_sets_id\n" +
            "        WHERE os.class = \"ORDER\"
    def orders = sql.rows(select)
    return orders
}
```

This is all working fine, the query returns exactly what I want and the  discriminator is working perfectly. In the database, I have a column called 'class' which holds the value.

However, in my test of this service method, the query fails, because

```
Column "OS.CLASS" not found
```

The SQL query that is executed and fails in the test, actually works against the real db, so somehow the discriminator column isn't being created via Spock/GORM/Hibernate Mixin.

Here is my test (I removed the boilerplate creating of objects for readability)

```
@Domain([OrderEnt])
@TestFor(OrderService)
@TestMixin(HibernateTestMixin)
class TestOrderServiceHibernate extends Specification{

void "get list of system order sets"(){
    given:
    // Orders are created, saved, and accessible via GORM (OrderEnt.get(id))

    when:
    def orders = service.getListSystemOrders()

    then:
    orderSets.size()>0
}
}
```

Comment: What version of Grails/GORM?

Comment: Its Grails 3.1.7 which ships with GORM 5 I believe. My guess here is user error, unfortunately I'm not sure what error that might be

Comment: Try using HibernateSpec to spin up an in memory instance of Hibernate instead of using the mock gorm